# RJ45 splitter slows down network speed?

Tags: networking, ethernet, splitter, rj-45, cat5e

My computer is connected to the wall socket via a RJ45 splitter, i.e. NIC-----spliter-----wallsocket. CAT5e cables are used.

Situation 1:
No cable in plugged into the third port of the splitter, then windows configure the network as 100Mbps.

Situation 2:
Another CAT5e cable is plugged into the third port of the spliter. The other end of this cable is FREE. Windows configure the network as 10Mbps.

I tried several times, same result.
Can anyone explain why?

NIC: Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-V (Intel H87 mainboard)
OS: Windows 7 (6.1.7601)

Comment: Third port of a RJ45 splitter? You can only split CAT5e to two devices. A male RJ45 goes to the wall and two female ports are to connect to devices. I also take it, that on the other side (i.e. router-side) a second RJ45 splitter is present? Do you have any make or model of this splitter? Not all splitters are for splitting network-signals (some are for phone-devices only).

Comment: You are using another splitter on the router-side, right ? Because splitters aren't switches, they just allow the signal of 2 cables to go into one, but you have to "de-split" it on the other end. the schematic would be : PC1/PC2==splitter--wallsocket--CAT5cable--wallsocket-splitter==switch--router--DSL...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't split RJ45 ehternet cables like that. The speed going to 10Mbit/s is because your device sees a horrible signal quality on the cable attached to it. If you need to connect multiple devices to one wall socket you need to attach an ethernet switch to the wall socket and connect your devices to that switch.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that a splitter is not a switch. I have two computers, but never use them simultaneously. I just use a splitter to avoid re-plug again and again. But i still wondering why an empty cable can slow down the speed, or cause "horrible signal quality".

Comment: @frozen-flame Unless your splitter is specifically designed for 100Mbps Ethernet, it's not going to work.

Comment: That's still not the way a splitter works unfortunately.

Comment: There will be signal reflection on the end of the inactive cable, which will disturb any signal between the connected device and the device at the other end of the wall socket. That will cause collisions like when using 10Base2 coax cabling.

Comment: @frozen-flame What can the empty cable do that won't cause a problem? It can absorb any signal that comes down it, but then half the signal is gone. It can reflect any signal that comes down it, but then the reflected signal will interfere with the original signal. How can it *not* screw things up?